# Bi-directional association between Footballer Mapper and Bowler Mapper

Tags: uml, bidirectional-relation, poeaa

This question is about a specific UML diagram in the book called Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture, by Martin Fowler.

Why is there a 'bi-directional association' between *Footballer Mapper* and *Bowler Mapper*
in the 'Inheritance Mapper' Class Diagram on page 302?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.

You're looking at an aggregation from the Player Mapper to one of the concrete mappers: Footballer Mapper, Bowler Mapper and Cricketer Mapper.

If you read the 2nd paragraph on page 304, he explains this design choice.

Comment: thanks. I just spotted it myself,too. For some reason I was seeing the line between the Footballer Mapper and Bowler Mapper as separate to the line between the Player Mapper and the Cricketer Mapper. doh!